# How to identify which column(s) have different value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has more than 100 columns, in normal case the `contract_id` should be unique in this table, but sometimes there are duplicate values. I use this SQL statement to retrieve data from this table:

```
select distinct contract_id, col1, col2,...colM 
from the_table;
```

but I found `contract_id` values, I know there should be some values are different in the same column(s), can I have a way to find out all these columns which have different value result in I saw duplicate `contract_id` even though I use distinct, because there are lots of fields and only a few columns have different values. It is difficult to compare each column one by one manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along

```
SELECT contract_id 
FROM the_table 
GROUP BY contract_id 
HAVING COUNT(contract_id)>1;
```

or

```
WITH NumberedRows AS
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY contract_id ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber
       ,*
 FROM the_table
)
SELECT * 
FROM NumberedRows
WHERE RowNumber>1;
```

The first will show you all the `contract_id` values, which occur at least twice, the second will show you all the rows you might want to manipulate (delete/change).

**attention**: I used `SELECT NULL` in the `ORDER BY` of the `OVER()` clause. It is very important to use a fitting `ORDER BY` clause here. This will be responsible for *Which row gets the number 1 and which rows get increasing numbers and will show up in the result due to `>1`?*